# Finding Maximum integer and minimum integer in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab4 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter integers (Zero to exit): ");

        //integers by value
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int evenNumber = -1;
        int oddNumber = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int largest = n;
        int smallest = n;
        int counter = 1;
        int total = 0;
        int average = 0;

        //boolean to end loop
        boolean done = false;

        //start of loop
        while (!done)
        {
            n = in.nextInt();
            total = total + n;
            //end loop method
            if (n == 0)
            {
                done = true;
            }
            //count number of integers entered
            else
            {
            count = count + 1;
            }
            //count of even numbers
            if ( n % 2 == 0){
                evenNumber = evenNumber + 1;
            }
            //count of odd numbers
            else
            {
                oddNumber = oddNumber + 1;
            }
            //find min and max integers !NOT WORKING!
            if (n > largest){
            }
            if (n < smallest){

            }
            if (count > 0){
                average = total / count;
            }
            else{
                    System.out.println("No Data Entered.");
                }
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of integers entered is: "+ count);
        System.out.println("Total even numbers entered: "+ evenNumber);
        System.out.println("Total odd numbers entered: "+ oddNumber);
        System.out.println("The largest integer: "+ largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest integer: "+ smallest);
        System.out.println("The average value is: "+ average);
    }
}
```

Above is my code, I have tried everything, I have not gotten any errors however the smallest and largest return does no come back correctly, I only get the Maximum integer if its positive and only minimum if user inputs a negative integer. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `I have tried everything` ... except for using `TreeSet`, which has the built in a ability to keep track of the min and max automatically.

Comment: @Tim that's a bit of a heavyweight approach to track max and min!

Comment: "I only get the Maximum integer if its positive and only minimum if user inputs a negative integer" this implies that you were using zero as your initial values of max and min, which isn't what is shown in your code.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is certainly overkill for this model problem, but in production, if you were already using a `Set` to store your data, I could justify switching to an ordered set if you wanted to take advantage of some of the summary methods which it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.min(int, int)` and `Math.max(int, int)` to find the `smallest` and `largest` respectively. You only need one `count`. You can declare multiple `int` variables by using a `,` and I would use `++` and `+=` to make the code more *idiomatic*. And you can use `break` to terminate a loop. Also, don't perform integer math for determining the average. Putting that together might look like

```
// integers by value
int n = in.nextInt();
int evenNumber = 0, oddNumber = 0, count = 0, total = 0;
int largest = n, smallest = n;
// start of loop
while (true) {
    n = in.nextInt();
    // end loop method
    if (n == 0) {
        break;
    }
    total += n;
    count++;
    // count of even numbers
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        evenNumber++;
    } else {
        oddNumber++;
    }
    largest = Math.max(n, largest);
    smallest = Math.min(n, smallest);
}
System.out.println("Total number of integers entered is: " + count);
System.out.println("Total even numbers entered: " + evenNumber);
System.out.println("Total odd numbers entered: " + oddNumber);
System.out.println("The largest integer: " + largest);
System.out.println("The smallest integer: " + smallest);
double average = total / (double) count;
System.out.println("The average value is: " + average);
```

You *could* eliminate the `break` by performing the **test** and **assignment** in the `while` loop conditional (this is another fairly common idiom)

```
while ((n = in.nextInt()) != 0) {
    total += n;
    count++;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        evenNumber++;
    } else {
        oddNumber++;
    }
    largest = Math.max(n, largest);
    smallest = Math.min(n, smallest);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you really simplified this, I had been at it for two days trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking n largest or smallest. But you are not doing assignment. Try this :

```
if (n > largest){
  largest = n ;
}
if (n < smallest){
  smallest = n ;
}
```

Comment: you also need to break when `n == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is using `List` and `Collections` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int evenNumber=0;
    int oddNumber=0;
    int total=0;
    int n;

    System.out.print("Please enter integers (Zero to exit): ");

    while(true){
        n = in.nextInt();
        if(n==0) {
            break;
        } else {
            list.add(n);
            total += n;
            if(n%2==0){
                evenNumber++;
            } else {
                oddNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println("Total number of integers entered is: "+ list.size());
    System.out.println("Total even numbers entered: "+ evenNumber);
    System.out.println("Total odd numbers entered: "+ oddNumber);
    System.out.println("The largest integer: "+ list.get(list.size() - 1));
    System.out.println("The smallest integer: "+ list.get(0));
    System.out.println("The average value is: "+ total/list.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was

```
int total = n;
int average = n;
```

in combination of needing

```
if (n > largest) {
  largest = n; // Probably already tried
}
if (n < smallest) {
  smallest = n; // Probably already tried
}
```

The unfortunate design decision to use the first element (nextInt) before the loop to have a correct largest and smallest initialized, probably led to this oversight.

Alternatively you could have done:

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and initalize the rest on 0, and call nextInt in the loop only.

As `average` is not used inside the loop, you can determine it outside.
You are doing integer division there, so might consider rounding:

```
int average = count == 0 ? 0 : (total + count/2)/count;
double average = count == 0 ? 0.0 : ((double) total) count;
```